# React Native Awesome Project on Android = blank screen & unable to pull up developer menu

Tags: android, react-native

Using React Native 0.43. Building to a connected Android device like so:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

The process builds and launches AwesomeApp on the device, but lands on permission screen with the title

> "Apps that can draw over other apps"

and the 'Permit drawing over other apps' toggle is set to active.

Clicking back button returns to main screen of app with blank white screen.

I have read that I might need to update the ip address, but a shake gesture does not pull up the dev menu.

In my android monitor, within Android Studio I see the following log:

> W/unkown:React Overlay permissions needs to be granted in order for
>   react native apps to run in dev mode.

I am having a hard time tring to fix this. Is this still an overlay permissions issue? How can I open up the dev menu to check the ip address? Anything else I might be doing wrong?

Update: This is occurring on a device (Pixel) running Android 7.1.2. Everything works fine on an S7 running Android 6.0.1

Comment: did you ever solve the white screen after pressing back from the permission screen?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue also. It ended up being a permissions issue.

When a ReactNative app launches, it loads a dialog that says it's loading the JS bundle. Make sure you have the following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

I had removed this permission, since I did not need it in the release version. But the debug version requires it.